# Project Reactor in onErrorContinue value that triggered error is null

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm having some issues with code written using project reactor:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Please consider the following code:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayBlockingQueue<Long> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

        startProducer(q);

        Flux.<Long> create(sink -> consumeItemsFromQueue(q, sink))
                .doOnNext(ctx -> System.out.println("Processing " + ctx))
                .flatMap(ctx -> Flux.push((sink)->{ throw new IllegalArgumentException("bum!");}))
                .onErrorContinue((ex, obj)->{
                    System.err.println("Caught error "+ex.getMessage() +" in obj:" +obj);
                })
                .doOnNext(element -> System.out.println("Do On NExt: " + element))
                .subscribe();

    }

    private static void consumeItemsFromQueue(ArrayBlockingQueue<Long> q, FluxSink<Long> sink) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                sink.next(q.take());
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.err.println("Error in catch");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void startProducer(ArrayBlockingQueue<Long> q) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    q.put(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Processing 1580494319870
Caught error bum! in obj:null
Processing 1580494321871
Caught error bum! in obj:null
```

According to the documentation in `onErrorContinue` the object should be the value that caused the error. Therefore I would expect it to be the `ctx` object from `flatMap`. Instead it is null.

Is this a bug or my understanding of the documentation is flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasoning about `onErrorContinue` behaviour can be rather counter-intuitive, so I always recommend avoiding its use where possible.

> According to the documentation in onErrorContinue the object should be the value that caused the error. Therefore I would expect it to be the ctx object from flatMap. Instead it is null.

Ah, but `ctx` *isn't* the value that caused the error, because your outer `flatMap()` call is working just fine - it's simply relaying an error that occurred in the *inner* `Flux` (the `Flux.push()` line in your example.) Since there's no value that caused this error (it just threw an exception), there's no value reported. So the behaviour you're reporting with this example is exactly what I'd expect.

If you changed that line to something like:

```
.flatMap(ctx -> Flux.push(sink -> sink.next(ctx)).flatMap(x -> Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("bum!"))))
```

...or:

```
.flatMap(ctx -> Flux.just(ctx).flatMap(x -> Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("bum!"))))
```

...Then you'd see something similar to `Caught error bum! in obj:1591657236326`, as there the exception actually *has* a cause, that is an error caused by an operator processing that value.